# Why does my generateUsername python sometimes return a TypeError (NoneType)?

Tags: python, string, function, typeerror, nonetype

I wrote a simple random username generator function, that returns the usernames as strings to be used in my other functions. It works properly, but on the odd occasion, it will return the error message:

"TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str"

Any idea what can be causing this? Find my code below.

```
def nameGenerator():
    # get user input
    num = 1
    # read word lists
    with open('src/nouns.txt', 'r') as infile:
        nouns = infile.read().strip(' \n').split('\n')
    with open('src/adjectives.txt', 'r') as infile:
        adjectives = infile.read().strip(' \n').split('\n')
    #read censor list
    with open('src/blacklist.txt','r') as inline:
        censored = inline.read().strip(' \n').split('\n')
    # generate usernames
    for i in range(num):

        # construct username
        word1 = random.choice(adjectives)
        word2 = random.choice(nouns)
        #check if word2 is censored
        if word2 in censored:
            i -=1
            continue
        #else make and print the username
        #captilaize first letter
        word1 =word1.title()
        word2 =word2.title()
        username = '{}{}{}'.format(str(word1), str(word2), str(random.randint(1, 150)))

        # success
        return (username)
```

Comment: one way would be, that the loop ended and you didn't provide what to return -> so return None

Comment: One problem is that if `word2` is censored the function will return `None`. Where is the error about concatenation coming from? Are you concatenating the result of this function?

Comment: @tromgy I am concatenating the result in another function yeah. The word2 issue could very well be the case. Would this fix it:
while word2 in censored:

            word2 = random.choice(nouns)

Comment: Yes, that will work. In this case you don't need the `for i in range` loop, which actually gave you this problem.